# Use AWK to print an adjacent field if a certain value is found in the line of a file

Tags: awk

I have the following DATA infile

```
 Cross,Tim,43560,0000000000,0000000000
 Smith,Sam,00000,4192125555,4192088888
 Williams,Jill,00000,0000000000,4199139999
 Wright,Mark,27645,0000000000,7042964444
 Alston,Jacob,00000,2025674962,0000000000
```

I need the output to label the corresponding fields if they are populated.  The target fields are **ZIP**, **HOME**, and **WORK** which are `$3`,`$4`,`$5` columns respectively from the infile.  If the value of any of the fields is null or 0, then the output field label corresponding will be empty.  Here is how the expected output should look:

```
 Cross,Tim,43560,ZIP,0000000000,,0000000000,
 Smith,Sam,00000,,4192125555,HOME,4192088888,WORK
 Williams,Jill,00000,,0000000000,,4199139999,WORK
 Wright,Mark,27645,ZIP,0000000000,,7042964444,WORK
 Alston,Jacob,00000,,2025674962,HOME,0000000000,
```

I've attempted to use AWK but can't seem to successfully do an `if` condition for more than 1 value against the `print`

code that hasn't worked

```
zip1=ZIP
home1=HOME
work1=WORK
awk -F ,  '{
        
        if ($3 ~ "00000")
                "'${zip1}'"=="";
        if ($4 ~ "0000000000")
                "'${home1}'"=="";
        if ($5 ~ "0000000000")
                "'${work1}'"=="";

        print $1 "," $2 "," $3 "," "'${zip1}'" "," $4 "," "'${home1}'" "," $5 "," "'${work1}'"}' $inputfile
```

This code just prints the vars without considering the `if` statements. If I print directly under 1 `if` statement, it will only print against that `if` of course.  Not sure how to have the single `print` recognize each `if` condition.

Comment: Please do add your efforts in your question, which is highly encouraged on SO.

Comment: Please read the description of e.g. the "linux" tag that you applied before you submit your question. As a new user here, also take the [tour] and read [ask].

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Could you please try following. Using ternary operator in `awk` here.

```
awk '
BEGIN{
  FS=OFS=","
}
{
  $3=($3==0?$3 OFS:$3 OFS "ZIP")
  $4=($4==0?$4 OFS:$4 OFS "HOME")
  $5=($5==0?$5 OFS:$5 OFS "WORK")
}
1' Input_file
```

***OR***

```
awk '
BEGIN{
  FS=OFS=","
}
{
  $3=($3 OFS) ($3==0?"":"ZIP")
  $4=($4 OFS) ($4==0?"":"HOME")
  $5=($5 OFS) ($5==0?"":"WORK")
}
1' Input_file
```

***Explanation:*** Adding detailed explanation for above.

```
awk '                                ##Starting awk program from here.
BEGIN{                               ##Starting BEGIN section from here.
  FS=OFS=","                         ##Setting field separator and output field separator as comma here.
}
{
  $3=($3==0?$3 OFS:$3 OFS "ZIP")     ##Checking condition if 3rd field is 0 then add OFS to it else add OFS and string ZIP to it.
  $4=($4==0?$4 OFS:$4 OFS "HOME")    ##Checking condition if 4th field is 0 then add OFS to it else add OFS and string HOME to it.
  $5=($5==0?$5 OFS:$5 OFS "WORK")    ##Checking condition if 5th field is 0 then add OFS to it else add OFS and string WORK to it.
}
1                                    ##Will print current line.
' Input_file                         ##Mentioning Input_file name here.
```

Comment: Very elegant answer and much simpler that what I was attempting.  Thanks